# How To Create Permission to google which pages don't index

Tags: html, security

i want to know how i can create permission on my pages until Google can't index that pages??
for example my website management pages

Comment: You need to learn about server-side code and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a robots.txt file at the root of your site to tell Google not to index a specific directory: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Example robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory-to-noindex/
```

Comment: More about robots.txt from Google Webmaster Tools: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robots.txt file to do that. Of course, some believe that it could not do that perfectly; however it is worth examining.

Also, Read these articles:

https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/68331?hl=en

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en

http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Google-Bot